# Main navigation bar and Vertical Navigation Bar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am creating a webpage with a top navigation, and a side navigation for browsing categories only, i want my navigation to be exactly like this:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

which is what i have, but this example is a responsive example, Im creating a fixed website. The thing is i dont want it in my .container div, i want it to be a side the container, but fixed, because at the moment what is happening is, my container is shifting behind my navigation when i resize my window smaller. What can i do to make it fixed aside my container div?

Here is my example: jsfiddle.net/susYE

Comment: Do have any code examples or snippets on e.g. jsfiddle? That would help a lot in clarifying your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/susYE/ here is an example

Answer (score 0):

See if this layout helps you: http://www.bootply.com/66638

The key is that I've included the side nav inside a row div, and I've used a nested container to hold the hero div and subsequent span4 divs.

For the nesting I've used container-fluid and row-fluid because they might be easier if you are new to nesting. If you don't want to use the fluid divs for the nesting you would need to change the three span4 divs to span3.

For more about nesting see fluid nesting on http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Once you get the basic scaffolding working the way you want, I think everything else will fall into place for you.

Good luck!